# Unit testing report script

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a report that runs every week. The class basically looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
class mailreport {
  public function exec() {
     users = Users::getAll();
     for u in users {
        r = this.generateReportData(u);
        m = this.generateMail(r);
        sendMail(u, m);
     }
  } 

  protected generateReport(User u) {
     // do lots of calculation, return report
  }

  // ...
}
```

Most of the bugs in this report are in the `generateReport`-method. It also does lots of pretty "pure" calculations, and would be easy to unit test if it weren't protected. The `exec`-method is hard to test because it has several dependencies and the output is a sent email with HTML.

How should I break out the `generateReport`-method so I can unit-test it more easily? I could of course create some kind of `Report`-class with a public `generate`-method, but then why not just have a stand alone function?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can unit test a protected method in PHPUnit with the following syntax:

```
$object = new MailReport();
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
$method = $reflection->getMethod('generateReport');
$method->setAccessible(true);

return $method->invokeArgs($object, [new User()]);
```

However, if your class is doing too much in one method, it might be a good idea to break it out. If you can get a unit test covering most of generateReport (or the new class), you can then refactor it into smaller methods and validate that it still works through the test.